# How can I save data to room just first time in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-room

I get some data from api in kotlin and save it to room. I do the saving to Room in the viewmodel of the splash screen. However, each application saves the data to the room when it is opened, I want it to save only once. In this case I tried to do something with shared preferences but I couldn't implement it. Any ideas on this or anyone who has done something similar to this before?

**hear is my code**

**my splash screen ui**

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    viewModel : SplashScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {




    val context: Context = LocalContext.current
    checkDate(context,viewModel)

    val scale = remember {
        Animatable(0f)
    }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
        scale.animateTo(
            targetValue = 0.3f,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 500,
                easing = {
                    OvershootInterpolator(2f).getInterpolation(it)
                }
            )
        )



        delay(2000L)
        navController.navigate(Screen.ExchangeMainScreen.route)
    }


    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_currency_exchange_logo_512),
            contentDescription = "Logo"
        )
    }

}



fun checkDate(context:Context,viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel){


    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("date",Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()


    val date = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
    val millis = date.time


    editor.apply{
        putLong("currentDate", millis)
    }.apply()


    val sharedDate = sharedPreferences.getLong("currentDate",1)
    println(sharedDate)
    val isDayPassed = (System.currentTimeMillis() - sharedDate) >= TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)

    if(isDayPassed){
       viewModel.update()
    }



}

}
```

**my splash screen view model**

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val insertExchangeUseCase: InsertExchangeUseCase,
    private val updateExchangeUseCase: UpdateExchangeUseCase,
    private val getAllExchangeUseCase: GetAllExchangeUseCase
) : ViewModel() {



    init {

        insertExchanges()
    }


   private fun insertExchanges() {

        viewModelScope.launch {

            insertExchangeUseCase.insert(DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
        }

    }


    fun update(){

        viewModelScope.launch {
            updateExchangeUseCase.updateExchange(getAllExchangeUseCase.get(DEFAULT_CURRENCY))
        }


    }


}
```

**In view model, insert is started automatically in init.**

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do something like this properly inside a Composable. Composables are only for creating UI. Remember the rule about no side effects. A function like your `checkDate()` should be called directly in `onCreate()` so it isn't called over and over as your Composition recomposes.

The problem with your current `checkDate` function: You save the "currentDate" every single this time this function is called, and you do it *before* checking what value was saved there before, so it will perpetually overwrite the old value before you can use it. You're also overcomplicating things by transforming the Long time into a Date and back to a Long for no reason.

Think about the logic of what you're doing:

- Update the data if it has been a day since the last time you updated it.

So to implement this, we **first** check if the previously saved date is more than a day old. Only if it is old do we write the new date and update the data.

Here's a basic implementation. This is assuming you want to update when it has been at least 24 hours since the last update, since that seems like what you were trying to do.

```
fun checkDate(context: Context, viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel) {
    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("date", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val lastTimeUpdatedKey = "lastTimeUpdated"

    val now = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val lastTimeUpdated = sharedPreferences.getLong(lastTimeUpdatedKey, 0)
    val isDayPassed = now - lastTimeUpdated > TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1)
    
    if (isDayPassed) {
        sharedPreferences.edit { // this is the shortcut way to edit and apply all in one
            putLong(lastTimeUpdatedKey, today)
        }
        viewModel.update()
    }
}
```

I would also change `"date"` to something longer and more unique so you don't accidentally use it somewhere else for different shared preferences. And I would rename your `update()` function to something more descriptive.

Don't forget to move the function call out of your Composable!